# how do I add a method in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText txtFirstNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFirstNum);
        final EditText txtSecondNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSecondNum);
        final TextView txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblResult);

        Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(txtFirstNum.getText().toString());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(txtSecondNum.getText().toString());
                int result = num1 + num2;
                txtResult.setText(result + "");
            }
        });

        Button btnSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
        btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {


                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(txtFirstNum.getText().toString());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(txtSecondNum.getText().toString());
                int result = num1 - num2;
                txtResult.setText(result + "");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

what I essentially want to do is use a method which I can call instead of repeating the same lines of code kind of like this (which does not work):

```
    int num1;
    int num2;
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            getNumbers();
            int result = num1 + num2;
            txtResult.setText(result + "");
        }
    });
```

...

```
private void getNumbers()
{
   num1 = Integer.parseInt(txtFirstNum.getText().toString());
   num2 = Integer.parseInt(txtSecondNum.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: that will work, but my guess is, you're a bit confused by scopes. in the original code, num1 and 2 are local variables, they can't directly be updated like this, instance or class variables can be

Comment: method should be `int doOperation(int num1, int num2, int operationType) { switch(operationType) { case ADD: return num1+num2; case SUB: num1-num2;..... and so on }}` ... with `operationType`  in button tag you would be able do this with 1 `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create two similar to `getNumber` methods but not `void`

```
private int getFirstNumber()
{
   return Integer.parseInt(txtFirstNum.getText().toString());
}

private int getSecondNumber()
{
   return Integer.parseInt(txtFirstNum.getText().toString());
}
```

and use them in:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int result = getFirstNumber() + getSecondNumber();
        txtResult.setText(result + "");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make num1 et num2 properties of the class